# Dynamically Fill in form from drop down selection

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the Following Form:
[image: Form]

How do i do the following:

When I chose a user from the select user drop down menu, After selecting the user I want to dynamically fill in the data below ? How do I do this without refreshing the page or loading another page?

I am using ASP.NET MVC

I would have to get the User ID from the Select User and then get the appropriate roles from the model

Comment: Make the Roles window a partial view, and do an ajax update of the same.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I know how to make it a partial view. But this is my first time diving into ajax, I would not know where to start. What is the reason of making Roles a Partial view if i may ask? Isnt it just rendered into one page anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX. Subscribe to the `.change` event of the DropDown, retrieve the selected value, perform an AJAX call to a controller action sending the selected value which will return as JSON the corresponding list. Then in the success callback of this AJAX call add the necessary information to the lists.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(function() {
   $('#id_of_your_users_ddl').change(function() {
       var selectedValue = $(this).val();
       var url = $(this).data('url'); // this assumes that you have appended a data-url attribute to your dropdown 
       $.post(url, { userId: selectedValue }, function(result) {
           // result will be a JSON list returned by your controller action
           // that you could use here to update your roles lists
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: What would the purpose of the data-url attribute be ?

Comment: To store the url of the controller action you are going to send the AJAX request to. It avoids you hardcoding it in your javascript file.